# ZEND PHP + JQUERY encoding issue

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

I know this topic was descibed few times so far, but here is mine strange one:

I have my database set to

> latin-2-general-ci

My page is set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
  <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
```

And here is issue when I try to use polish letters i.e."ą / ł"
I have to seprate ways to add information to my MySQL base. 
First using AJAX-JQUERY- polish letters are no stored as it seems to look but like something like this:

> Ał?

, but suprisingly, when I use JS to put them in the screen looks good - ą
Second with zend_form - added information directly using only PHP code, chars are stored exact way i type them - in my database: łołoł but when JS try to read it these chars are ommited f.e

> Database: łołoł
>
> View: oo

Any idea how to solve it?

Regards 
Radek

Comment: You should be using utf-8 throughout the entire pipeline. Taking latin-2 out of the db and dumping it into a utf-8 environment won't work.

Comment: change everything into utf-8 still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using application.ini configuration file just put this lines in:

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf-8"
```

Comment: I set this options and I do make sure that i'm using everywhere utf-8still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the encoding set correctly (preferably all to 'UTF-8') on:

- The [database connection](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)
- PHP's output header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
- The HTML meta header

And be sure you're not doing any weird stuff in between (like calls to `utf8_encode`). You need to have all your bases covered for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not doing weird thing like utf8_en... but could you please give ma suggestion how to set database connection using zend framework? Thank you a lot